# How to sort sql query result pivotally

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table with the following columns

```
Create table TestTemp (id int, usernm varchar(15), subject varchar(25), score int)

Insert into TestTemp(id, usernm, subject, score) values (1, 'abc', 'english', 40)
Insert into TestTemp(id, usernm, subject, score) values (2, 'abc', 'maths', 60)
Insert into TestTemp(id, usernm, subject, score) values (3, 'abc', 'science', 55)
Insert into TestTemp(id, usernm, subject, score) values (4, 'efg', 'english', 46)
Insert into TestTemp(id, usernm, subject, score) values (5, 'efg', 'maths', 49)
Insert into TestTemp(id, usernm, subject, score) values (6, 'efg', 'science', 80)
```

I want the result to be displayed in this format

```
Usernm english maths science
abc    40      60     55
efg    46      49     80
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT usernm, [score], [Subject]
    FROM TestTemp
) DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([score]) FOR [Subject] IN ([english], [maths], [science])
) PVT
```

For more information check this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).